# css changing my elements

Tags: html, css

so i have a question...
Im making a website and i encountered a problem. I made my website in the resolution 1920*1080p and obviosly when i change to a different size all the elements get moved around. what i want to do is make it so no elements get moved everything is were i want it to be, and if your on your phone youd need to scroll not only down and up but left and right, i'll post my code.

http://pastebin.com/5vzrHq2b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set

```
body {
    width:1920px;
    height:1080px;
}
```

I also totally advise you against doing this, it makes websites extremely annoying. You should code the wesbsite to be manageable on all displays.

Comment: Ok thank you! and yes ik what you mean ill make a seperate stylesheet for small displays such as phones

Comment: @Frager: He specifically stated he wants it in p

Comment: Although the images still move is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Put those elements into divisions. and when defining the division class make the position option "absolute". 
you can define a division class as follows.

```
.division1{
       position: absolute;
       height: .......;
       width: ........;
       .
       .
       .
 }
```

and use it as follows

```
 <div class = division1>
       //Everything that you want to make unmovabl1e
 </div>
```